# Seattle.html and Oslo.html not visible in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jquery

The book I'm using as a resource to add jQuery to our SharePoint Online site discusses editing the Seattle.html and Oslo.html files in SharePoint designer. However, those files are not appearing in designer. How can I view these files? If I cannot view them, should I be modifying my html/css/jQuery in another way?

[image: SharePoint Designer Master Pages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, i find the **oslo.master** or **seattle.master** and edit the master page, you can find in your SharePoint Design Master Page on navigation menu, this option show all masterpages in your site, and click on seattle or oslo and edit file in advanced mode.
I strongly advise you to make a backup of one of the two and modify your backup.

Like this exemple.
[image]

Comment: So basically, use the .master files and edit those? I'll act like the book is telling me that. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, exactly edit .master files i'm sure resolve your problem.